# How to handle group radio button in React JS - FUNCTIONAL COMPONENT

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to select only one option in the group of radio buttons. i can only find class component code online.
Also help me with a onChange function to handle this.

```
const [radioOption, setradioOption]= useState(true)

const handleRadioChange = () =>{

}
    return(
<>
<Form.Group 
    inline 
    style={{
        display:'flex',  
        justifyContent:'space-between'}}
    >
    <Form.Radio
    onChange={handleRadioChange}
    value="All devices"
    label='All devices' 
    defaultChecked/>

    <Form.Radio
    onChange={handleRadioChange}
    value='Mobile only'
    label='Mobile only'/>

    <Form.Radio
    onChange={handleRadioChange}
    value='Desktop only'
    label='Desktop only'/>

</Form.Group>


</>)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To select only `one option` in the `group of radio buttons` you need to use `same name` in every `input of radio`. To save your choice we can use `useState`. Here is the complete example:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Demo() {
  const [gender, setGender] = useState("Male");

  function onChangeValue(event) {
    setGender(event.target.value);
    console.log(event.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <div onChange={onChangeValue}>
      <input type="radio" value="Male" name="gender" checked={gender === "Male"} /> Male
      <input type="radio" value="Female" name="gender" checked={gender === "Female"}/> Female
      <input type="radio" value="Other" name="gender" checked={gender === "Other"} /> Other
    </div>
  );
}

export default Demo;
```